# Ignore word in a string defined by quotes using RegEx

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to match specific words that are not part of a string. How to do this with RegEx.
This expression finds all instances \b(?i)MyName\b
I would only like MyName to in the second line of the following paragraph.

```
"Do not match MyName between these quotes"
 Match MyName here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do this kind of thing is to match the two possibilities in different capture groups (which you can identify after with \1 or \2 or $1 or $2)

```
{"[^"]*"}|{yourword}
```

or

```
("[^"]*")|(yourword)
```

cause text between double quotes is match first, the second group can only contain words that are not between double quotes.

Comment: This worked. I ended up using ("[^"]*")|(\b(?i)myname\b) to ignore casing and set boundares, then evaluated the groups.

Answer (score 0):

`^[^"]*(MyName)[^"]*$`

This expression matches lines with MyName that is not between quotes, and returns MyName as a match group.

http://rubular.com/r/LSzdiuHqVq

Comment: Thanks, but that matched the entire sentence. I was hoping to only match the word MyName in the second line.

Comment: There are the `()` brackets for. They create a match group only on that name.